# I want to show lists under sidebar div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I'm coding a project listing page in bootstrap and I'm stuck with an issue.I have a sidebar with a fixed height where I list the checkboxes and I have a main container beside the sidebar which lists the product. By default the area under the sidebar is empty. [default style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Wow.jpg)

Is there anyway I can list the products under the sidebar as shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhFzm.jpg)

> I want to show lists under sidebar and all the items should be in a single row

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');

aside {
  background: #ddd;
}
.row {
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.col-sm-4 {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <aside class="col-sm-3">
    <ul>
      <li>Checkbox</li>
      <li>Checkbox</li>
      <li>Checkbox</li>
      <li>Checkbox</li>
      <li>Checkbox</li>
      <li>Checkbox</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <main class="col-sm-9">
  <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      </div>
  </main>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**see code below** (here is fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/7q9hkrcb/)

```css
@import url('//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');

aside {
  background: #ddd;
}
body{
  margin-top:20px
}
.row {
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.col-sm-6 {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.col-sm-4 {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <aside class="col-sm-4">
    <ul>
      <li>Checkbox</li>
      <li>Checkbox</li>
      <li>Checkbox</li>
      <li>Checkbox</li>
      <li>Checkbox</li>
      <li>Checkbox</li>
       <li>Checkbox</li>
      <li>Checkbox</li>
      <li>Checkbox</li>
      <li>Checkbox</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      
      </div>
      
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      </div>
      
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me if you need help

Comment: thanks for your help. Can I achieve the same effect with all items in a single row?

Comment: as I think , no!